# Debugging .DLL file - Missing entry: function

Tags: c

I seldom post here. But I would appreciate assistance as to debug my .DLL file.
Error I am running into when running the .DLL with rundll32.exe is: "Error in pwned.dll - Missing Entry: CreateTextDocument"

I am trying to achieve a simple goal of creating and writing to a file on the user Desktop.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

void __stdcall CreateTextDocument(HWND hwnd, HINSTANCE hinst, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    // Get the path to the user's desktop folder
    TCHAR szFolderPath[MAX_PATH];
    if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_DESKTOPDIRECTORY, NULL, 0, szFolderPath)))
    {
        // Append the filename to the desktop folder path
        TCHAR szFilePath[MAX_PATH];
        _stprintf_s(szFilePath, MAX_PATH, _T("%s\\MyTextFile.txt"), szFolderPath);

        // Create the file
        HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(szFilePath, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
        if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            // Write some sample text to the file
            char szText[] = "This is some sample text that will be written to the file.";
            DWORD dwBytesWritten;
            WriteFile(hFile, szText, sizeof(szText), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);

            // Close the file handle
            CloseHandle(hFile);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox(hwnd, _T("Error creating file."), _T("Error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox(hwnd, _T("Error getting desktop folder path."), _T("Error"), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    }
}
```

I tried running the .DLL file through the Windows command prompt the following ways:
rundll32.exe mydllfile.dll,CreateTextDocument & rundll32.exe mydllfile.dll

Comment: I think you need something like `__declspec(dllexport)` on the function declaration to make it visible as an exported function.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Thanks for you reply, it didn't seem to solve said issue. I guess I am a bit out of depth here.